# Can residents of another state(say WA) have a driving license in California?

Tags: california, dmv

Asking for my girlfriend. She lives in WA where we do not have a car there but visits me in CA frequently. And we have our car in CA, which she needs to drive. She does not have a WA license and does not plan to have one for WA. Since she does not need one.

Comment: She won't be able to get a California driver's license unless she's a resident of California.

Answer (score 2):

### You have to reside in California to hold a California driver's licence

Since your girlfriend lives in Washington she can't get a California licence. The good news is she can get a Washington licence and use it in California.

More generally, most places in the world allow "foreigners" (interstate OR international) to use their foreign licence to drive.

Comment: and related, if you are a resident of CA, you need to have a CA driver's license (there are exceptions).